# Combining percentage from different categories

Tags: percentage

I have to combine two percentages from different categories, which are questions answered / total questions:

1. 2/10 * 100 = 20%
2. 3/6 * 100 = 50%

- I combined both percentages ((20+50)/2)*100 = 35%
- But if I combine all questions and total questions which is 5/16 and the total percentage of the combing values is 31.2%.

**Which is the correct way to calculate the percentage of the combined categories?**

Comment: Could you explain what the "combined" percentages are intended to mean?  Only then can anyone tell you what might be a correct way.

Comment: Its the overall percentage of the question answered/total questions) in all categories

Comment: In that case, you'll want to use the second approach. Think of an extreme case where Category A has 1 question, and Category B has 1000 questions. If somebody answers the question from A, but 0 questions from B, the first method would suggest that they answer 50% of the questions, clearly not what you are looking for.

Comment: What if i dont have information like total questions. I only have percentages. Then what should do?